# App services behind Applicaiton Gateway and applicaiton authentication using Azure SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an application which I am trying to migrate to the App services. The authentication was windows auth before migration so I moved it to Azure SSO.

**Background** -

- The application is registered within Azure to leverage single sign on
  and we have a reply URL configured within the application and
  redirect URI configured in Azure SSO for URL -
  https://abc.customdomain.com
- The app is hosted within App services and the Azure endpoint URL of
  the app services is https://abc.azurewebsites.net
- We have also setup a TXT record created within the custom Domain and
  added this to App service to verify the ownership of the DNS.
- The custom DNS https://abc.customdomain.com is configured and
  pointing to the application gateway.
- The application gateway is configured to point to the App service.

**Issue**
When I try testing the application the SSO works as expected but the moment it tries redirecting to the application after Sign on it breaks because of the incorrect redirect URL as the app services has the URL – https://abc.azurewebsites.net

After setting up a CNAME and pointing it to the App services the hosted site works, but we want to have the traffic flow from the Application gateway.

Comment: So for the application to be routed through the application gateway you need to do dns mapping from domain provider (godaddy) to your application gateway endpoint and then your application gateway will redirect it to your web app where.

Comment: As I stated above - "The custom DNS https://abc.customdomain.com is configured and
pointing to the application gateway and the application gateway is configured to point to the App service." but it doesn't work.